# PL/SQL Function returned without value

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle11g

I wrote below `FUNCTION` to check given `reference number` is exist.

```
FUNCTION find_reference_no(
    p_ref_no IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS

  v_ref_no varchar2(50);

BEGIN

  select REF_NO into v_ref_no from cash where REF_NO = p_ref_no;  
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    v_ref_no := '#';

RETURN v_ref_no;    

END;
```

I have called this function in a `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`. when I'm inserting data, Ii'm getting error as

`ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value`

How can I solve this ?

**PS:** I'm not inserting data into `cash` table. I'm inserting data into another table (assume it is table B) and called this function in it's (table B) `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`.

Comment: This sort of lookup in triggers is precisely the sort of we we should avoid doing in a trigger.  It is a hidden performance on every insert, and will harm the scalability of your application.

Comment: Instead of prefixing your parameter name with p_, consider prefixing the parameter name in the query with the name of the function -- ie. "where cash.ref_no = find_reference_no.ref_no". The v_ is also redundant as a prefix on the variable, which should also be data typed as cash.ref_no%Type rather than varchar2(50).

Comment: The reason the problem is not obvious is that you have misleading code formatting - the RETURN statement *looks* like it's part of the normal  processing for the function, whereas it's actually within the EXCEPTION block for the function. The EXCEPTION keyword should really be at the left-hand margin, same level as the BEGIN and END - for clarity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All functions must execute a RETURN statement.  Your function has the RETURN in its exception block, so that statement won't get executed in normal circumstances.

Enclosing `select` statement by additional `begin end` block with its own `exception` section will solve your problem. So your function might look like this:

```
create or replace function find_reference_no(
    p_ref_no IN VARCHAR2) return varchar2
AS
  v_ref_no varchar2(50);
begin
  begin
    select REF_NO 
       into v_ref_no 
       from cash 
      where REF_NO = p_ref_no;  
  exception
     WHEN no_data_found THEN
          v_ref_no := '#';
   end;
  return v_ref_no;    
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the function just returns the same value as the parameter if it exists in the table, you could avoid the awkward use of exception handling and rewrite this as:

```
  function find_reference_no(
      ref_no in varchar2)
  return varchar2
  as
    row_count integer
  begin
    select count(*)
    into   row_count
    from   cash
    where  cash.ref_no = find_reference_no.ref_no and
           rownum      = 1

    if row_count = 0
      return '#'
    else
      return ref_no
    end if;

  end find_reference_no;
```

I'd return a 1 or 0 (ie. the value of row_count) to indicate that the record does or does not exist though.

```
  function find_reference_no(
      ref_no in varchar2)
  return varchar2
  as
    row_count integer
  begin
    select count(*)
    into   row_count
    from   cash
    where  cash.ref_no = find_reference_no.ref_no and
           rownum      = 1

    return row_count

  end find_reference_no;
```